# How to get administrative permissions in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

my dvd-rw was not working. but i had to install linux. so i installed ubuntu from the iso using demons tool. But when i am opening the terminal to create an user,it's prompting that only root have the permission to create an user.

i am trying to use "su" command but it's showing that authentication failed.

How can i become the root?

Comment: Please use question titles which describe the question. it's a about ubuntu doesn't help us help you. Also try to use complete sentences and capitalization.

Comment: They disabled root on your machine because they knew you'd misuse it.

Answer (score 4):

sudo -i 
then type your pass
and you will root

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo bash
```

instead.  You may also wish to install a graphical environment, such as KDE or GNOME; they offer their own ways to issue commands as root.

Answer (score 0):

To become root type:

```
sudo su -
```

It is however more secure and "better" to do everything using the `sudo` command to elevate privileges on a per command basis rather than logging in as root.

Comment: sudo -i does the same thing in one command

Answer (score -1):

If you are like me and really want to use su and understand why it is disabled, one of the ways to do it would be:

```
sudo passwd root
```

or just

```
sudo passwd
```

This will allow you to create password for root and you will be able to use that user normally.

Comment: Ig the OP understood why it is disabled, he wouldn't need to ask the question.